# Sending a request with a random string does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request

I am trying to send a get request to a site.
This worked flawlessly but now i want to add a random string after the request URL. But that does not seem to work unfortunatley.
I think its because the option parameter can not access anything else but idk, I would appreciate it a lot if someone could look into this and help me out.

```
    ....
    const chalk = require("chalk")
    require('console-stamp')(console, { 
    format: ':date(yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss.l)' 
    } );
    var randomstring = require("randomstring");
    let rndmstring = randomstring.generate({
    length: 12,
    charset: 'alphabetic'
    });

const options = {
    url: 'https://www.requesturl?search=housenumbers&'+ rndmstring,
    method: "GET",
    gzip: true,
    proxy: reformatProxy(proxies2[randomproxy]),
    headers: {
        "method": "GET",
        "scheme": "https",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
        "cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.984479855.1612702925; _gid=GA1.2.658293268.1613141568; _gat_UA-168024539-1=1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
};

...

setInterval(() => {
    request(options, callback)
}, delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this just to kill any cache? If so, using a date stamp is much easier and doesn't require an extra library

```
url: 'https://www.requesturl?search=housenumbers&ck='+ new Date().getTime(),
```

Comment: Yes it’s just to kill the cache. The problem is tho that it does not work with the random string library. Will this fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also append **`uuid`** to the `urls`.

```
import { v1 } from 'uuid';

let url=`https://www.requesturl?search=housenumbers&ck=${v1()}`
```

**With require statement**

```
const uuid =require('uuid').v1
let url=`https://www.requesturl?search=housenumbers&ck=${uuid()}`
console.log(url) // https://www.requesturl?search=housenumbers&ck=6f56a3d0-d067-11eb-9259-bb2ebfa7bd2e
```